# cant schedule prometheus-server pod on kubernetes, pod reports taints but nodes dont have any taint

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

i am getting

```
0/7 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 5 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

for my prometheus server pod but if i check each nodes there are no taints. and there is enough cpu and memory to be allocated.. what am i missing here?

i tried deleting the pods and even the deployment object but the error still persists

all nodes have 0 taints..
this is a fresh prometheus install on a new kubernetes cluster
the yaml files that i have used to work until now when i needed to deploy a new kubernetes cluster

Comment: For example master nodes have special taints on them which prevent usual pods from running on them. Do you have 2 master nodes?

Comment: Can you show info of nodes (Specifically their taints and affinity details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0/7 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 5 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.

The message is specific: it's not the *taints* that are keeping your prometheus pods off of your workers, it's the **volume** that is the problem. If you are in AWS, it's because your volume is in an availability zone that your workers are not (so, a `us-west-2a` volume and `us-west-2c` workers, for example)

The shortest path to success in your situation may be to either recreate the volume in the correct A.Z. if it was empty, or manually create a new volume and copy the data into an A.Z. that matches your workers, or (of course) spin up a new worker in the A.Z. that matches the volume

> all nodes have 0 taints..

Is for sure not true for two reasons: because the scheduler clearly says there are two Nodes with taints, and because unless you specifically stripped them off, the masters are almost always(?) provisioned with `node.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` taints explicitly to keep workloads off of them

Comment: i certainly missed that part about the master nodes being unschedulable by default. thanks! I can narrow down my debugging to PVs now..